# Ping multiple hosts and execute command

Tags: shell, ping, hosts

I'm very new in bash scripting and unix so I will need some help on this.I have 7-10 hosts which I want to ping from one of the servers via cronjobs. What I want is when host is up to execute command on it. When is down do nothing.

I don't want logs or any messages.
So far I have this and unfortunately don't have ability to try it right now. If you can just check it and point me.

```
#!/bin/bash
servers=( "1.1.1.1" "2.2.2.2" "3.3.3.3" "4.4.4.4" "5.5.5.5" "6.6.6.6" "7.7.7.7" )

for i in "${servers[@]}"
do
  ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null  
done

ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then

    if [ $STATUS >= 2 ]; then
        echo ""
    fi
else
    while [ $STATUS <= 1 ];
    do 
       # command should be here where is status 1 ( i.e. Alive )
       /usr/bin/snmptrap -v 2c -c public ...
    done
fi
```

I'm not sure if this is right or no. I've used this from one tutorial and there is some things that I'm not sure what they exactly do.

Am I on right way here or I'm totaly wrong?

Comment: Instead of pinging the hosts first ([LBYL — Look Before You Leap](http://oranlooney.com/lbyl-vs-eafp/)), why don't you just run the command you intend to run (EAFP — Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission). If the hosts is up, the command will work and if the host is down, it simply won't work.

Comment: The point is that this will be somethik like alarm manager. I mean I have one web page where I have computer icons for every host. When I ping them if some icons turn `red` that means is down and when is green is up. Your comment make sense just I want to do it in this way. Thank's

Comment: I rolled back your edit to a previous version of your question. Your edit completely re-wrote the question making the answers you have received irrelevant. If you have a new question, please post it separately. If you have a simple follow-up question, [edit] it into this one _but don't remove the original version_, just add to it.

Comment: @terdon, thank you. I will have this in my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made some comments in line to explain what different parts of the script are doing.  I've then made a concise version of the script below.

```
#!/bin/bash
servers=( "1.1.1.1" "2.2.2.2" "3.3.3.3" "4.4.4.4" "5.5.5.5" "6.6.6.6" "7.7.7.7" )

# As is, this bit doesn't do anything.  It just pings each server one time 
# but doesn't save the output

for i in "${servers[@]}"
do
  ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null  
# done
# "done" marks the end of the for-loop.  You don't want it to end yet so I
# comment it out

# You've already done this above so I'm commenting it out
#ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null

    # $? is the exit status of the previous job (in this case, ping).  0 means
    # the ping was successful, 1 means not successful.
    # so this statement reads "If the exit status ($?) does not equal (-ne) zero
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        # I can't make sense of why this is here or what $STATUS is from
        # You say when the host is down you want it to do nothing so let's do
        # nothing
        #if [ $STATUS >= 2 ]; then
        #    echo ""
        #fi
        true
    else
        # I still don't know what $STATUS is
        #while [ $STATUS <= 1 ];
        #do 
           # command should be here where is status 1 ( i.e. Alive )
           /usr/bin/snmptrap -v 2c -c public ...
        #done
    fi

# Now we end the for-loop from the top
done
```

If you need a parameter for each server, create an array of parameters and an index variable in the for-loop.  Access the parameter via the index:

```
#!/bin/bash
servers=( "1.1.1.1" "2.2.2.2" "3.3.3.3" "4.4.4.4" "5.5.5.5" "6.6.6.6" "7.7.7.7" )
params=(PARAM1 PARAM2 PARAM3 PARAM4 PARAM5 PARAM6 PARAM7)

n=0
for i in "${servers[@]}"; do
    ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null  

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
       /usr/bin/snmptrap -v 2c -c public ${params[$n]} ...
    fi

    let $((n+=1)) # increment n by one

done
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I believe i've meaned `$i` where is `$STATUS`. Is just this 10 lines? With one cronjob I can run this script let's say every 1 hour and will check servers from the list and execute command if the server is alive? Also do I need something more or this is just enought to run command `/usr/bin/snmptrap -v 2c -c public ...`?

Comment: I haven't tested it but this should be all you need.  You can give it a shot and let me know if there is a problem.  Whatever terminal commands you put between the `if` and `fi` will run for each server that's up.

Comment: Note that in the for-loop, `$i` is the IP address of the server, not the status of the server.  You will probably have to use `$i` in your `snmptrap` command.

Comment: Ok, thank you again. I will test it a little later and will write if there is some problem.

Comment: I think I don't need to use it in `snmptrap` since when see server alive will execute the command without matter what IP is.

Comment: OK.  I'm not familiar with that command so I was just assuming (incorrectly).

Comment: And last question in server list can I write `IP:PORT` like `1.1.1.1:1234` or must be only the `IP` without `port`?

Comment: This won't work because whatever you put in that array will be passed to `ping` and you can't ping specific ports.  See [this question](http://serverfault.com/q/309357/169422).

Comment: Uh, actually I connecting to the machine like this `IP:PORT`

Comment: maybe, but you do not connect to the machine with `ping`.  `ping` cannot be made to use a different port.  See the question that I linked for an alternative to `ping`.

Comment: Yes, I just read the question. Thank's again. I will let you know a bit later what is the result from this script.

Comment: Here I get this error `Line 7: [: -eg: binary operator expected`

Comment: You have a typo.  It's `-eq` as in "equals", not `-eg`.

Comment: Oh, I see where is the problem. Thank's. One more thing since this is working can you also help me how to put one more variable and when ping first server from the array will show something like `1` then ping second server and change this parameter to `2` and so on.

Comment: I guess I will need one more array after server array but how I will read this in command and associate to the server?

Comment: @IvanPetrov, this is very simple to do, but please edit your question with this request in it so that it's clear to future visitors why answers are including this bit.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I've been edited my question and think is ok now. For me is not that simple to do this. I've how I was think will be but it's not like this.

Comment: Thank's for the edition. I've got some errors. First on line 5 where is `n = 1` and where n incrementing by one. The error say `command not found`. Here `n = 1` and here `$((n+=1))`

Comment: Sorry, I let some python syntax slip in.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: Now there is no errors but I don't get `param1` it's started from `param2`. EDIT: I've change `n=0` and now starting from `param1`.

Comment: And now I tested it on leave server and it's work perfectly. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Even more concise

```
#!/bin/bash

servers=( "1.1.1.1" "2.2.2.2" "3.3.3.3" "4.4.4.4" "5.5.5.5" "6.6.6.6" "7.7.7.7" )

for i in "${servers[@]}"; do
    ping -c 1 $i > /dev/null && /usr/bin/snmptrap -v 2c -c public ...
done
```

NOTES: The "&&" after ping means "IF TRUE THEN", and in the case of ping, TRUE means ping did not fail (i.e. the server successfully responded to ping)

Comment: This work perfect. Tested on my local on VM. I'll try tomorrow on the real server and will write and accept. Thank you